# Run mbunit 3.1 tests in resharper 4.5

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, mbunit

I have earlier used mbunit 2 and with [this plugin](http://code.google.com/p/mbunit-resharper/) I could get my tests to run in the resharper test dialog.

Now with mbunit 3.1, I read that I didn't need any external plugin. So I donwloaded Gallio and got the new MbUnit.dll. Added a reference to it in my test-project.

Now it looks correct in visual studio. I've got the green/yellow circles next to the methods.
But if I click and choose run, the test doesn't run. They appear in the resharper test dialog, but with a red line striking over the text and the icons being grey. No error message so it's hard to see what's wrong.

How do I get it to work? How do I see what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should just work out of the box.  I presume that you installed Gallio, didn't just grab the dlls out of the zip file or something.

Three things to try:

1. Add a reference to Gallio.dll.
2. Be sure to remove any remaining references to the old MbUnit v2 MbUnit.Framework.dll.
3. Look in the Visual Studio Output window for log messages.